# Вывести одномерный массив

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет) Есть матрица 100x100. Нужно просуммировать каждый столбец матрицы, полученную суму каждого столбца поделить на количество элементов в нем и полученный результат занести в одномерный массив.
С суммированием столбцов и с количеством элементов я вроде бы разобралась)

```
public class Etalon {

    public static void etalonMatrix(int [][] convertToMatrix) {
            int [][] mas = convertToMatrix;
            int s = 0;
            int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < convertToMatrix[0].length; i++){
                s = 0;
                k=0;
                for (int j = 0; j < convertToMatrix.length; j++){
                    s = s + mas [j][i];
                    k++;

                } 
             /** System.out.println(s);

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(k);*/
               }
          }
     }
```

А передать все это в одномерный массив у меня не получается(

Comment: А в чем затруднение? Создаете массив и в цикле по I после расчета присваивает в него результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Etalon {

    public static void etalonMatrix(int [][] convertToMatrix) {
            int [][] mas = convertToMatrix;
            int [] result = new int[convertToMatrix.length];
            int s = 0;
            int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < convertToMatrix[0].length; i++){
                s = 0;
                k=0;
                for (int j = 0; j < convertToMatrix.length; j++){
                    s = s + mas [j][i];
                    k++;
                    result[j] = s;
                } 

                  }

                  for(int p = 0; p < result.length; p++){
                     System.out.print(result[p]+" ");
                  }

          }
     }
```

Попробуйте так, возможно допустил ошибку по невнимательности, но суть такая.

Comment: спасибо большое все верно))) только перебирать массив нужно по i.